# Can get XML Data through "Postman software" but I cannot get data through SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, xml, api, postman

Using Postman I can get XML data:
[Postman image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Htw6r.png)

However, When I follow the tutorial and using SWIFT language to parse XML data, the URL became "invalid".
[SWIFT parsing url code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoW2p.png)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuoXQ.png)

Please help me out. How come this happened?

The testURL is this format: [testURL format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q485J.png)

Comment: On the console Xcode Print: "Return Nil from reading String URL"

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59059655/edit) your question to include the relevant code *as formatted text*, rather than images.  From your question's current content and your comment, it would seem that `testURL` doesn't contain a correctly formatted URL.  What is its value?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What made me confused was that why the postman can parse the "URL", and swift cannot?

Comment: The URLused in Postman and swift code are same

Comment: Without seeing at least something of the URL, I can't say.  The URL may include characters that Swift needs to be URL encoded (percent encoded) while Postman handles this for you.  All I can say is that `testURL` isn't valid.

Comment: the testURL format is : http://www.XXXXtech.com/net/WebService.aspx?Login=XX@XXXXXtech.com&EncryptedPassword=XXXXXX&EDI_Name=Generic\Customers&SELECT_Columns=CustomerID&WHERE_Column=CustomerID&WHERE_Value=0000

Comment: That \ looks suspicious for a start.

Comment: I revised the question. Please refresh the page to see the image format testURL. Thank you

Comment: Please stop pasting images into your question - Paste text.

Comment: I use "\\" to escape in swift code. So, the URL is as same as in the Postman

Comment: OK, I am new for using this website to ask the question, I will try to learn how to use this website. Thank you for your recommendation

Answer (score 0):

From your comment it seems that `URL()` is returning `nil` - This indicates that it was unable to create a valid URL from the provided string.

You need to percent encode your URL to ensure that any characters that are not permitted in the URL.

In this case it is the \ in the `EDI_NAME` parameter.  Even though you may have used `\\` in your string literals, `\` is not valid in the query string of a URL.

You can use the `addingPercentEncoding` method of `String` to ensure that the URL is encoded correctly.

```
let stringURL = "http://some.host.com/net/WebService.aspx?Login=someUser@some.com&EncryptedPassword=XXXXXX&EDI_NAME=Generic\\Customers&Select_Columns=CustomerID&WHERE_Column=CustomerID&WHERE_Value=0000"

if let encodedString = stringURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed), let validURL = URL(string: encodedString) {
    // Do something with validURL
} else {
    print("Unable to create URL")
}
```

This will result in the `EDI_NAME` parameter being converted to `EDI_NAME=Generic%5CCustomers` - The \ has been percent encoded.

Postman is probably performing this percent encoding for you, to make things easier.

Comment: Oh, OK, your answer makes me clearer. Let me try your code provided. Thank you for your answer. I appreciate it.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you so much and I appreciate it!!!!

Comment: Good to hear.  Since my answer helped you, you should click on the "tick" to accept it.